# Google Maps JavaScript API key does not work after associating the billing account

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, api-key

In a Javascript-based project, I used Google Maps API (**with a JavaScript API key generated by an account without billing account associated to**). It correctly worked for about two years. Last week I noticed some issues about maps, as you can see in the following picture:

[image]
In the Chrome Console, I read the following warning:

```
Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
```

Then, as a workaround, I associated a billing account to my Google account, and with it I generated a new Google Maps JavaScript API key. So, i put the new key in my project.

Unfortunately, nothing changed, I have the same issue and the same warning from the Chrome console.

Moreover, I have 5 installations of that software, running on different servers, with the same API key (**without billing account**): maps work for two installations. Why?

Comment: Did you check if your new api key is active?

Comment: @FernandoSouza Yes, I did it. It's active.

Comment: Are the "working" servers on older domains?

Comment: @geocodezip Older domains? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Have any of the servers been live, serving Google Maps for longer than the others?  Are any of them newly registered, or just started using the Google Maps APIs?  You mentioned it worked for about 2 years, on all the different domains/servers?

Comment: @geocodezip In the meaning you explained, some server is older than others. The two servers correctly running maps, are "differently" old: one of them is old, while the other one is the newest of the pool.

Comment: How about the domains they are serving are they old or new?

Comment: @geocodezip Same domain.

Comment: Test your page with [Google Maps Platform API Checker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-maps-api-checker/mlikepnkghhlnkgeejmlkfeheihlehne) extension in Chrome browser. You will see what URL is used to load Maps JavaScript API and what key is included in this URL. It looks like currently the API key is not included properly.

Comment: This might have something to do with the error you're receiving: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing